# iAd + mobclix separate integration

Tags: iphone, ios, iad, ads, mobclix

I am new in the ad-sector, I have programmed two little ios games to test how useful ads are 
and which revenue they earn.
And I am very impressed, about the performance, and so I would like to sell a free version of my 5 months old Music-App, to increase paid sales and get a little revenue from ads in the free version.

The problem: The two live apps have iAD intigreated throught mobclix, and I turned off auto optimization to handle the networks. BUT OFTEN I SEE THE iAD TEST AD.
Mobclix says that when iAD cant deliver an AD it goes to the next network, something must be
wrong, in addition to this I live in AUSTRIA (iAD is not supported), and mobclix says that they don't send requests to apple from countries they aren't supported, but they do...

Yet I've turned the Allocation in Mobclix down to max. my impressions.I would like to call iAD in more then 90% of the requests and if they cant deliver an AD an other network should show something.

IS it possible to integrate iAD separate and call it every time and when they received an error, or that iad cant fill the space to call mobclix. I think this would be better because, I can turn on the mobclix optimization.

First ad data:

iAD: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzH6G.png
 Mobclix: https://i.stack.imgur.com/54IZy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that. If you wanted to try iAd first you would just manually try an iAd and then if this delegate function gets called:

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Then you try mobclix. You can choose to remove the failed iAd at this point or you can keep it and it will still try to fetch ads for you. If it receives one and fires:

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
```

You can remove the mobclix ad so the iAd is shown.